# asp-route id doesn't pass the correct ID when having 2 joined tables

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing a web application, using ASP.Net

I have two models,

the first, Users:

```
public class Users
 {
     [Key]
     [DisplayName("__ Users UserID __")]
     public int UserID { get; set; }
     
     [StringLength(7)]
     [DisplayName("User LAN ID")]

public ICollection<WorkView>? WorkView { get; set; }
 }
```

The second, WorkView:

```
public class WorkView
        {
            [Key]
            [DisplayName("** WorkView ID **")]
            public int ID { get; set; }
    
            [DisplayName("** WorkView mainUserID **")]
            public int? mainUserID{ get; set; }
    
    
    public Users? Users { get; set; }
            public string? FirstName { get; internal set; }
            public string? LastName { get; set; }
            public string? UserName { get; set; }
            public string? JobTitle { get; set; }
            public string? OfficeLocation { get; set; }
            public string? ManagerFirstName { get; set; }
            public string? ManagerFamilyName { get; set; }
            public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
```

That is the Controller:

```
[HttpGet("WorkView/{id}")]
//Opening the WorkView Creation
public async Task<IActionResult> WorkViewCreate(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Users == null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var workView = (from w in _context.WorkView
                    join u in _context.Users on w.mainUserID equals u.UserID
                    where (w.mainUserID == id)
                    select new WorkView
                    {
                        ID = w.ID,
                        mainUserID = u.UserID,
}).FirstOrDefault();

    var workViewTest = _context.WorkView;

    Console.WriteLine("workView.ID = " + workView.ID);
    Console.WriteLine("workView.mainUserID = " + workView.mainUserID);  
    return View(workView);

}
```

and eventually my view:

```
<script src="~/js/workViewScript.js" defer>
</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="WorkViewedit" asp-route-id="@Model?.OfficeLocation">

    <div style="border:ridge;background-color:lightsalmon;">
        <label asp-for="mainUserID"></label>
        <input asp-for="mainUserID" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="mainUserID" aria-describedby="basic-mainUserID" ;" style="width:auto;" />
    </div>
    <div style="border:ridge;background-color:lightsalmon;">
        <label asp-for="ID"></label>
        <input asp-for="ID" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="ID" aria-describedby="basic-ID" ;" style="width:auto;" />
    </div>

    <div style="border:ridge;background-color:lightsalmon;">
        <label asp-for="mainUserID"></label>
        <input asp-for="mainUserID" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="mainUserID" aria-describedby="basic-mainUserID" ;" style="width:auto;" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    
</form>
```

My problem, is when my View is opening, I have the Users ID used in it, instead of the WorkView ID...

I don't see what causes that, no matter what I'm changing in the models, the view or the controller, I'm only getting the same ID, so I can't save anything from my view, as the ID is not the correct one.

I'm running a "check" in the controller, and I do have the correct ID's

workView.ID = 472

workView.mainUserID = 23

but once I'm returning the View, the workView.ID returning the mainUserID, which is the Users one. And it's not correct.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I would really appreciate any idea.

Cheers

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've removed images to put code as text

Comment: Hi @Hakeem, why is your view contain duplicated ID and mainUserID? Could you pls share a gif to show your operation and displayed result.

Comment: Hi @Rena, that was just for testing purpose, the result is just displaying the ID, no errors, just the wrong ID. I've corrected it to be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this could help, I fixed my issue by using

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

in my controller before returning the View.